# ever Had vs ever have

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

I saw this headline days ago: *Trump is the worst President we ever* ***had***.

My question is why did they use *had* instead of have? The President office still exists, so why use ***had***? Shouldn't it be: *Trump is the worst President we ever* ***have***.

Comment: Your last example, though grammatical, does not have a meaning appropriate to this discussion. It could only refer to something habitual in the present, and I haven't been able to think of a plausible example of it. I think you mean _the worst president we have ever had_.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, **Trump is the worse president we have ever had** because the line of president extends from a point in the past right up to the present.

But headline writers are not much concerned with grammar. They simply want to get their point across and encourage their audience to read the article. Moreover they might argue that all the previous presidents are in the past.

I should add that this question concerns grammar rather than fact, although it may accord with both.

Comment: I think it's only "strictly speaking" [we should use Present Perfect] because the ***main*** verb is Present Tense. If that first verb is also a past tense, Simple Past is actually correct: *Trump **was** the worse president we ever **had*** (though arguably that does perhaps call into question the matter of whether we continue to have presidents now and into the future! :)